# NestedScrollView: line 1722 pos 12: 'result': is not true

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I've a Flutter application that have a `NestedScrollView` with this structures:

```
Scaffold
    body: NestedScrollView
        headerSliverBuilder: SliverAppBar
        body: SingleChildScrollView
```

when I scroll the contents of SingleChildScrollView, I get the following error randomly:

```
The following assertion was thrown while notifying listeners for AnimationController:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 1722 pos 12: 'result': is not true.
```

And the SliverAppBar does not collapse.

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance! :-)

Comment: refer official documentation for SliverAppBar [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/floating-app-bar)

Comment: I haven't a List but only a SingleChildScrollView